# Alternative to remotely importing modules in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a script with 3 parts(remoteScript, script.ps1, and the modules) that is executed remotely. The first part handles the authentication for the remote execution using credssp. This script, lets call it remoteScript, uses invoke-command to execute another script.

```
$script =
{
    Invoke-Expression ("{0}\script.ps1" -f $PSScriptRoot)
}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "computerName" $script -Authentication Credssp -Credential $cred
```

---

script.ps1 imports various modules that contain the cmdlets for the execution of the body. The problem is that the modules are located on the host computer. In order for the remote computer to run the script, it needs access to the modules. In this case the remote computer can't connect back to the host computer in order to load the modules.

1. I could either put all of the cmdlets from the modules into the script body, resulting in a massive script that nobody wants to read/maintain.
2. I could try to load the modules in the remoteScript, then use export-pssession to export all of the currently loaded cmdlets to a known location on the remote computer. Then the script would load the exported pssession.

I'm not entirely sure how I'd do the latter or if you can even use export-pssession to export them to a remote computer. The closest parameter I found relating to that is [-OutputModule](http://ss64.com/ps/export-pssession.html), but I think that you'd need a share on the remote computer in order to save the pssession there.

I'm open to any thought/ideas/feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can run local functions on remote computer by using the `${function:<FunctionNameHere>}` syntax, have you tried that?

It works like this:

```
# Define a simple function locally
function Get-Stuff { param($stuff1,stuff2) Write-Host "$stuff1 $stuff2" }

# Similar to calling Get-Stuff "stuffArgument1" "stuffArgument2"
# Keep in mind that you can only give positional arguments using this method
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "computerName" -ScriptBlock ${Get-Stuff} -ArgumentList "stuffArgument1","stuffArgument2" -Credential $cred
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot.